# Redirecting to another html page while consuming RESTful API with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, spring-boot

I'm implementing a web application on Spring boot, in the back-end I need to implement RESTful API, and in the front-end I need to consume it using jQuery (unfortunately).
My main screen (index.html) is just a Persons list screen: list of people names, each of them is clickable. When the users click the name of any person in the list, Person Edit form should be provided (filled with the given person's data).
I was thinking my API shouldn't care about the redirecting thing, that's why I wrote this in my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/person/{id}")
public Person findById(@PathVariable String id) {
    Long personId = Long.parseLong(id);
    return personRepository.findOne(personId);
}
```

And in the front-end I'm trying to make an AJAX call to this endpoint, but I can't understand where do I do the redirecting part.
I've tried something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/person/' + id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = "personForm.html";
        $('#myDiv').append(data.title);          
    }
});
```

but everything after `window.location.href = "personForm.html"` just doesn't happen. Besides using `window.location.href`seems an ugly solution. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) if you want to simulate an HTTP redirect.
For example:

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

By the way, if you want to simulate a click by link, you use `location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute javascript after a redirect, since your current page will get unloaded.
You can add url parameters, so redirect to something like
 `window.location.href = "personForm.html?"+data.title;`.

On that page you can get the data from the url using `window.location.search`, and edit your page with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a url paramter of id to the clicked user and then when you are on the user form page grab the information of that user via the call you're already doing, then you don't need to redirect.

```
<a href="personForm.html?id=1234">John Smith</a>
```